# How to hide specific <a onclick=""> </a> buttons with custom CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if this is even possible however we use a 3rd party SAS system which provides various levels of Admin control / access for our staff when they login.

The system is embedded in our site with their web-snippet and we can control / affect most elements with custom CSS.

We want to hide/not display 3 x "buttons" that appear on the nav menus on various pages with .

We have used display:none like this for elements with names: i.e.

```
body #SFctr #SFevtmnunte { display: none !important; }
```

This seems to work great for removing all of the elements that we want to hide that have class names?, however we have these 3 "on-click" elements that we need to hide:

```
<a onclick="SF.open('!event/new')">Add New Event</a>
<a onclick="SF.lib.dsp('SFevtdbdscl',true)">Embed/Link</a>
<a onclick="SF.evt.dbd('atg',this)">Export <span data-fld="atg">QuickBooks</span></a>
```

The SAS provider will not create a special level of access for us so I'm wondering is there a way I can use something in our custom CSS to over-ride these buttons appearing?

These 3 on-click's are static and the code always looks like this. Can anyone assist with hiding these 3 elements with CSS please?

EDIT
To add some maybe need info - the on-click use used in many places so we can't block them all. At this stage we only need to block these three.  I used FF inspector can provide the following additional info:

```
<a onclick="SF.lib.dsp('SFevtdbdscl',true)">Embed/Link</a>
innerhtml: Embed/Link
outerhtml: <a onclick="SF.lib.dsp('SFevtdbdscl',true)">Embed/Link</a>
css selector: #SFevtdbd > div:nth-child(1) > nav:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(3)
css path(important bits): div.SF_li div#SFctr.SF div#SFpne.SF3 div#SFevtpne.SFpne div#SFevtdbd.SFevtpne div.SFbox nav a
xpath: body/div[4]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/nav/a[3]


<a onclick="SF.evt.dbd('atg',this)">Export <span data-fld="atg">QuickBooks</span></a>
innerhtml: Export <span data-fld="atg">QuickBooks</span>
outerhtml: <a onclick="SF.evt.dbd('atg',this)">Export <span data-fld="atg">QuickBooks</span></a>
css selector:  #SFevtdbd > div:nth-child(1) > nav:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(5) 
css path(important bits): div.SF_li div#SFctr.SF div#SFpne.SF3 div#SFevtpne.SFpne div#SFevtdbd.SFevtpne div.SFbox nav a 
xpath: /html/body/div[4]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/nav/a[5]


<a onclick="SF.open('!event/new')">Add New Event</a>
innerhtml: Add New Event
outerhtml: <a onclick="SF.open('!event/new')">Add New Event</a>
css selector: #SFevtcalnav > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)
css path(important bits): div.SF_li div#SFctr.SF div#SFpne.SF3 div#SFevtpne.SFpne div#SFevtcal.SFevtpne nav#SFevtcalnav ul li a
xpath: /html/body/div[4]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[7]/nav/ul/li[2]/a
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said those buttons are always static, you can try targeting the attribute `onclick` plus the value. This will select those buttons specifically, unless there are other that have the same `onclick` value as them

```css
a[onclick="SF.open('!event/new')"],
a[onclick="SF.lib.dsp('SFevtdbdscl',true)"],
a[onclick="SF.evt.dbd('atg',this)"] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="SF.open('!event/new')">Add New Event</a>
<a onclick="SF.lib.dsp('SFevtdbdscl',true)">Embed/Link</a>
<a onclick="SF.evt.dbd('atg',this)">Export <span data-fld="atg">QuickBooks</span></a>
```

Another test for assurance:

```css
a[onclick="SF.open('!event/new')"] {
  color: red;
}

a[onclick="SF.lib.dsp('SFevtdbdscl',true)"] {
  color: blue;
}

a[onclick="SF.evt.dbd('atg',this)"] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="SF.open('!event/new')">Add New Event</a>
<br/>
<a onclick="SF.lib.dsp('SFevtdbdscl',true)">Embed/Link</a>
<br/>
<a onclick="SF.evt.dbd('atg',this)">Export <span data-fld="atg">QuickBooks</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide **all** `<a>` elements that have an `onclick` attribute, you can target it like this:

```
a[onclick]
{
    display: none;
}
```

Otherwise, you'll need a more specific selector. If these are inside an identified element, like a header, you can target them by putting the parent element's selector before the `<a>` selector.

```
#parentElementID a[onclick]
{}
```

Comment: See above additional info as requested -I'll try the answer from Swellar and report back !

Answer (score -1):

You can use attribute selector in css to hide the links as follows:

```
a[onclick] {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Repeating previous answer. Either add something to it or give something new.

Comment: When I started writing the answer there was no other answer for the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a selection based on content, using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a:contains("Add New Event")').hide()
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Thanks Gerfried - Needed CSS for this but this may also come in handy!